# How to run GitHub Action on PR comment edit?

Tags: github-actions

I want to trigger a job when the first comment of a PR is edited. With "first comment" I mean the initial text the author has entered to open the PR.

For issues, this triggers whenever the first comment of an issue is edited:

```
on: [issues]
  types: [edited]
```

But for PRs, this (even without any type filter) doesn't trigger, when the first comment is edited:

```
on: [pull_request]
```

The fact that there is no type filter makes is seem as if `pull_request` was the incorrect trigger. I understand that a PR is just an issue with code. So I would assume that `on: [issues]` should trigger when the first comment of a PR is edited, but also that is not the case.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [edited]
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request):

> By default, a workflow only runs when a pull_request's activity type is opened, synchronize, or reopened. To trigger workflows for more activity types, use the types keyword.